# How do we find a time-independent Hamiltonian that generates a given unitary transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, unitarity

I know that for time independent Hamiltonians  we can make the statement

$$U = e^{-iHt}\tag{1}$$

where $H$ is a time-independent Hamiltonian (divided by $\hbar$) and $U$ the unitary, also known as time evolution operator.

Now when studying I've met a unitary which corresponds to a two-level rotation defined as

$$U = \lvert i \rangle \langle j \rvert +\lvert j \rangle \langle i \rvert -\lvert i \rangle \langle i \rvert - \lvert j \rangle \langle j \rvert + \mathbb{I}\tag{2}$$

For clarity for a 4 state system it would look like this

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
0& 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

I'd like to understand how I can ever hope to use eq. (1) to obtain such a unitary eq. (2).

Comment: Are you familiar with exponentials of Pauli vectors such as  $\exp(i\pi \sigma_1 /2 )=i \sigma_1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In general** Unitary matrices are generated by Hermitian matrices, so you need a *basis* of Hermitian matrices $\left\{ \mathbb{I},T^a \right\} _{a=1,\dots ,N^2-1}$ for an  $N$ dimensional Hilbert space (edit: see note at bottom).

For $N=2$ one usually chooses the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). For $N=3$ the [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices).

**In this case** one need not be so methodical. First note that for a Pauli matrix:

$$ e^{-i \theta \sigma} = \mathbb{I}\cos{\theta}-i\sigma \sin{\theta} $$
$$ \Rightarrow e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}\sigma} = i\sigma$$
$$ \Rightarrow e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}(\sigma-\mathbb{I})} = \sigma$$ (prove this using a power series)

Now notice that your unitary operator can be thought of as "$\sigma_{x}^{i,j}$" + the identity for all other indices. Hence a good guess would be:

$$ e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}(\sigma_{x}^{i,j}-\mathbb{I}^{i,j})} 
\tag{1} $$

where here $\sigma_{x}^{i,j}$ is understood as having 0-s in all other indices, e.g.:

$$\sigma_{x}^{i,j}-\mathbb{I}^{i,j}= \begin{bmatrix} 
-1& 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1& -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2} $$

(Check that it works)

Edit: Actually there is a simpler way of finding such a Hamiltonian in general, without finding a basis!

*Diagonalize the unitary* - it will then have the form:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}e^{iE_{1}}\\
 & e^{iE_{2}}\\
 &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & e^{iE_{N}}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now in this new basis the Hamiltonian is obvious.

Comment: Made some corrections. If you include $\mathbb{I}$ in your basis you can produce all elements of $U(N)$ and not just the special unitaries.

Comment: 1. Hey so first of all thank you for your time (:
But to be honest I am not quite sure where are you getting at.
Let me recap what I know: 
We have a particle in a some potential, which gives us the Hamiltonian. Now I can use that Hamiltonian to determine the energy-eigenstates and eigenvalues of said particle in said potential.
I am thinking that the Hamiltonian is in the energy eigenbasis such that we have the eigenvalues on the diagonal $\mathrm{diag}=\{E_1,E_2,...\}$
And obviously this Hamiltonian can be used to derive the time evolution of a any state.

Comment: 2. But suddenly you are trying to convince me that in order to generate such unitary I am asking for I need to consider that the hamiltonian can be described via the pauli matrix? 
Sorry I haven't seen that before. I am used to think of the Hamiltonian as Energy operator, so it makes no sense for me why I'd re-write him as pauli matrix.
Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @CatoMaths This is just a trick based on the properties of the Pauli matrices; given the final form of your unitary (it's diagonal in a $2\times 2$ subspace), it's likely the trick will work and indeed it does.  Your Hamiltonian here would be (2) and you can verify that (1) actually produces the unitary you want.

Comment: @CatoMaths any Hamiltonian is Hermitian and so can be written using a basis of Hermitian operators (e.g. Pauli matrices). One simply needs to pick the right Hamiltonian and evolve for the right 'time' (in this case angle) to get the desired unitary.

Comment: Hm, so I tried to diagonalize as you suggested (I think). I diagonalized the maxtrix from eq. (2) [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-diagonalization-calculator/diagonalize%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D-1%261%260%260%5C%5C%20%20%201%26-1%260%260%5C%5C%20%20%200%260%260%260%5C%5C%20%20%200%260%260%260%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D)

Which doesn't seem useful to me. I must be missing something :/

Comment: @CatoMaths yeah that looks good, now just exponentiate and apply the inverse transformation, a.k.a. $U= P^{-1} \exp\left(\frac{i \pi }{2} D \right) P$.